# Playing Video in HTML email via HTML5

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, html-email

I'm trying to get an MP4 video playing in an email via HTML  tag. (code below).

This code has been taken and adapted from a trusted source (http://www.emaildesignreview.com/email-design-best-practice/html5-video-in-email-1149/), however said source states that it should play on iPad/iPhone.

At the moment, I can only get it to play on Apple Desktop mail and Hotmail(now outlook).

The iPad/iPhone recognise this as a media file, but refuse to play it. Is there something wrong with my code, is there something missing?... or is the world just not ready for this yet?

Thanks

```
<video width="328" height="242" poster="backup.png" controls="controls">
        <source src="videosource.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <a href="http://mywebsite.com/video"><img src="backup.png?1363867422" width="328" height="242" /></a>
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done a fair bit of testing with HTML5 video, and unless you're just sending to people you know will open with iOS devices, it just isn't worth the hassle at the moment.

I wrote this a while back and the same thing is still very much true: http://jacques.corbytue.ch/blog/html5-video-in-email-one-step-closer/

As far as your code, try using absolute URL's instead of relative ones.